# isShiftDown when JButton pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, keylistener

Hi all
I have a JFrame and I've added a JButton to that JFrame.
Also I've added an ActionListener to my JButton.
Now please convert this Pseudocode to Java :

```
public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (isShiftDown)
        print "Shift is Down.";
    else
        print "Shift is Up.";
}
```

Actually I want to know isShiftDown while my JButton pressed or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace `isShiftDown` by

<del>`(e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0`</del>

`(e.getModifiers() & ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0`

getModifiers() returns a bitmask of all modifiers pressed during an event (alt, ctrl, shift...) that you can bitwise-and to get the status of one of them. Pretty much what it says in the doc.

**Edit:** As of Java 9 it is recommended to use `InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK`

**Edit2:** In this case([ActionEvent#getModifiers() (Java SE 9 & JDK 9)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getModifiers--)), should use `ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK` instead of `InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK`

- [ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK) : 1
- [InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) : 1 @Deprecated(since="9")
- [InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK) : 64

Comment: Sure, getModifiers() returns a bitmask of all modifiers pressed during an event (alt, ctrl, shift...) that you can bitwise-and to get the status of one of them. Pretty much what it says in the doc. Can you accept my answer if it suits your needs?